# Flatten parent child hierarchy using gcp Data Fusion

Tags: python, sql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

I have employee data which has employee as well as manager columns. I need to flatten out the hierarchy and have that code running in a data fusion pipeline. I found Python and SQL code online that could flatten out the data. But, I don't know how to run it in the pipeline I'm new to GCP. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

[FlattenRecord transform](https://github.com/data-integrations/hierarchy-plugins/blob/develop/docs/FlattenRecord-transform.md) might be what you're looking for.

You can also execute custom python code using the [python transform](https://github.com/data-integrations/python-plugins/blob/develop/docs/PythonEvaluator-transform.md).

If you need the equivalent of a hierarchical SQL queries (CONNECT BY PRIOR), you can look into using [hierarchical to relational](https://github.com/data-integrations/hierarchical-to-relational/blob/develop/docs/HierarchyToRelational-sparkcompute.md) plugin.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the FlattenRecordTransform and I think it's for nested data not hierarchal. Although I think the hierarchal to relational plugin is helpful, I couldn't find it  in data fusion. The python transform plugin is throwing this error- Error encountered while configuring the stage: 'null'. I think this is a bug in the plugin. Can you please help me out.